# SQL query syntax in CASE WHEN ELSE END to count

Tags: sql, count, sum, case, case-when

Writing a query to find the number of ED visits that were discharged from non-ED units.
The column dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C column stores 1 if the unit was an ED unit.
Assume NULL values are non-ED units for the purpose of this query.
Which of the following produces this number?

I am thinking it is A because in my mind, that sound the correct syntax.
COUNT(CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END standard format)
A has that.
B doesn't have the THEN? so it is incorrect syntax?
Please help me understanding the nuances between these choices.

A.)

```
COUNT( CASE WHEN dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C is NULL  OR dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C <> 1 THEN NULL 
            ELSE 1 
            END )
```

B.)

```
COUNT( CASE WHEN dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C is NULL or dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C <> 1 
            ELSE NULL 
            END)
```

C.)

```
CASE WHEN dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C Is NULL or dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C <> 1 THEN COUNT (NULL) 
     ELSE COUNT (1) 
     END
```

D.)

```
CASE WHEN dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C is NULL or dep.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C <> 1 THEN COUNT(1) 
     ELSE COUNT(NULL) 
     END
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: what is ED? i don't know what you want please show us some data

Comment: ED is Emergency Department

Comment: Are you using Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL...?

Comment: SQL Server. But this is theoretical question.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the records that are returned COUNT(*) and put the condition in the where clause.

If you are using Oracle, you can use NVL. 
The sample below is for Oracle, but if using mysql or SQL server, you can use the ISNULL Function.

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dep WHERE NVL(ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C, 0) != 1`

It looks like however, you are joining this to another table, probably a visit table. So, you want to count visits. Visits probably stores some kind of department id or way to join it to departments.

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit v, departments d WHERE v.dep_id = d.dep_id AND NVL(d.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C, 0) !=1
```

If you want the entire list like shown above, you want to use a group by. This will show you the count for each visit by department type.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visit v, departments d GROUP BY d.ADT_UNIT_TYPE_C
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated with this.